# Creating simple rule in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, lexical

I need to make a rule in my lex file that will identify the start of a newline and a sequence of  spaces I did this `^( )*` but the compiler says it is wrong what is the right way to define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
^[\n\t ]+
```

Comment: The problem of that way is that the `scanf` will stop reading exactly when it finds one of those symbols, so he would have to re-scan again, to find out if next is another accepted character.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto there's no `scanf` here, that's a `lex` expression that matches white space at the beginning of a line :)

Comment: if I want to print them should I do this printf("%s",yytext)